# Getting text in a bootstrap form to align

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I get the customer code and name to be aligned like address inputs?

Is there some kind of container I can put raw text into?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-horizontal" name="editForm" ng-submit="editForm.$valid && vm.save()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Code</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      {{vm.customer.code}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      {{vm.customer.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="address1">Address 1</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="address1" name="address1" type="text" maxlength="50" ng-model="vm.customer.address1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="address2">Address 2</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="address2" name="address2" type="text" maxlength="50" ng-model="vm.customer.address2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question I have found the container I was looking for is a p with the class form-control-static.

This makes static text in a form line up with the labels and inputs exactly like I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling variables, which should be defined in project scope

For example put

```
<script>
var vm = {
  customer = {
    code: 123
  }
}
</script>
```

Somewhere before your html, or just define these variables in separate .js file in your project and import it to your .html template with for example:

```
<script src="mydata.js" />
```

I assume you're using handlebars, so you might want to read their quick tutorial, it's really helpful. http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: I am asking about the bootstrap form and the text alignment. The AngularJS code is all fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the `control-label` class, which applies a `text-align: right` property to the texts.

[image]

There are many ways to solve this. I will list a few:

1. Either remove the class `control-label`, which will drive all the texts to the left side by default & will look equally aligned.
2. Or you can leave the `control-label` class & override the `text-align` property to left using your own stylesheet.
3. If you are not interested in the left aligned approach or think the gap between is too much, then the best solution is to modify your layouts a little and remove the `control-label`. **Divide the labels into 1 + 1 columns instead of 2.** This is what it would look like.

---

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      {{vm.customer.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helped